# Does CoffeeScript have a class destructor?

Tags: javascript, class, timer, coffeescript

When a CoffeeScript class is instantiated a constructor called.  This works.  However, now I would like to delete a instantiaed object.  Is there any destructor to call? (I would like to clear a timer)

Comment: No, you have to do that manually. Do you want a method that is invoked by garbage collector runs or what?

Comment: I could have a method that I call to "destroy" the object.  I was wondering if there was a more formal method.  I was also wondering if there were a way to delete an instantiated class

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This isn't possible with JavaScript so it is not possible with CoffeeScript. If you have some clean up to do, you need to determine by yourself when the right moment is.